# Update function doesn't work correctly

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm developing a simple game of zombie survival.
This script is attached in an empty GameObject, which acts as the player's health.

```js
#pragma strict

var health = 100;
var attack = 10;
var otherAttackDelay = 5;

function Attack1 () {
    health -= attack;
    Debug.log ("Under Attack 1!");
    yield WaitForSeconds (otherAttackDelay);
    Attack2 ();
}

function Attack2 () {
    health -= attack;
    Debug.log ("Under Attack 2!");
}

function Update () {
    if (health == 80) {
        Debug.log ("Die!");
    }
}
```

The player has 100 health, and attack a zombie is 10. There are 5 second delay before the zombie attack again.

In the function Update I wrote a condition, if the player's health is equal to 80 (2 attacks) will display a Debug log with the message "Die!"

The problem is that when the zombie attacks only once (90 of life would there) immediately shows the "Die!". What am I doing wrong?

Greetings.

Comment: Theres quite a few typos here like `attack var = 10;` and `health - = attack;`

Comment: Yes, sorry. I don't speak english, that is a translator error. I'm fixing the code now.

Comment: Does "Under Attack 2!" get logged out before "Die"? i.e. is Attack2() getting called immediately after Attack1()?

Comment: Where's Attack1() being called? Are you sure only one place is calling it and only once?

Comment: Are you using the onTriggerEnter() to invoke these attack methods? There is a chance that your logic there that might be giving you this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the health constantly in the Update function. In either Attack1 or Attack2, or better, both, you could check the health at the very end. If that doesn't work, I also suggest sticking a debug log showing the players health either in the update or the attack functions, so you can make sure the health isn't going to 80 like you want it to. Also, I noticed you are checking an exact amount, which can be kinda sketchy when checking things like health. Try doing something like if (health <= 80) versus (health == 80). That way, if you do decide to stay with checking the health in the update function, it won't miss the players health being 80.

Hope this helps!